# Are two commas needed around proper noun in article title?

Tags: commas, titles

Suppose the title of an article were to describe a new service:

> New service Blank offers summer jobs for students

I’m wondering if the rules are bent somewhat for titles of stories, or are the commas are still necessary?

> New service, Blank, offers summer jobs for students

Answer (score 1):

You are correct - grammar and punctuation rules can be bent in titles.  The most obvious examples of this can be found in newspaper headlines.

This is a nice summary of [headline grammar](http://www.chronicle.com/blogs/linguafranca/2013/02/18/the-grammar-of-newspaper-headlines/).

Comment: Nevertheless, whether or not to include a comma is purely a stylistic decision.